Neo4rs rust panic when executing query with large result set
I am using neo4j 4.4.32 and trying to connect and query with rust neo4rs client:
async fn get_transactions(pin:String, graph:Graph) -> Result<Vec<Transaction>, neo4rs::Error>  {
let query_string = r#"
        match (c:Company {pin:$pin})-[:DECLARES]->(t)
        return t.transactionId as transactionId, 
        t.values as values,
        t.dates as dates limit 50"#;
    
    let mut res = graph
            .execute(query(query_string).param("pin", pin.clone()))
            .await
            .unwrap();
        
    
    let mut vector:Vec<Transaction> = Vec::new();

    while let Ok(Some(row)) = res.next().await {
        
        let transaction_id = row.get::<String>("transactionId").unwrap();
        let values = row.get::<Vec<f64>>("values").unwrap();
        let dates = row.get::<Vec<String>>("dates").unwrap();
        let transaction = Transaction {
            transaction_id:transaction_id.clone(),
            values:values.clone(),
            dates:dates.clone()
        };
        vector.push(transaction);
    }
            
    Ok(vector)

}
Removing the limit from the query causes a set_len out of bounds and subsequent panic:
panicked at /Users/kpassadis/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/bytes-1.6.0/src/bytes_mut.rs:511:9:
set_len out of bounds
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/129f3b9964af4d4a709d1383930ade12dfe7c081/library/std/src/panicking.rs:652:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/129f3b9964af4d4a709d1383930ade12dfe7c081/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::panicking::panic
             at /rustc/129f3b9964af4d4a709d1383930ade12dfe7c081/library/core/src/panicking.rs:146:5
   3: bytes::bytes_mut::BytesMut::set_len


This should never happen. Your code triggered UB without any unsafe code, which means there definitely is a (severe) bug in your dependencies. Please report it.

However, the life of the maintainers will be much easier if you will provide them with a Minimal Reproducible Example.

A full backtrace (set RUST_BACKYTRACE=full) will also be helpful.

What version of neo4rs are you using?

I am using 0.7.1

I am working on a fix.

PR submitted: https://github.com/neo4j-labs/neo4rs/pull/178.

It seems that the issue is related to the java lists returned in the query. If bounds are applied to the returned lists in the query e.g. values[0..1000] then there is no panic.

This is a (severe, soundness) bug in neo4rs. I submitted a PR to fix it. After it is published, you can just upgrade. In the meantime, you can patch it.
